# Trigonometric Function

Tags: trigonometry

I've tried to use all the available trigonometric identities but I still can't find a way to solve this problem.

transform $(2 \sin 50000n\pi - \sin 1000000n\pi)$ to $2 \sin n\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: $n$ is an integer?  If so, you know $\sin(50000n\pi)=0$, right?

Comment: Thanks so much for the hint. If both is 0, why will I get 2 sin (n*pi/2)?

Comment: @www "why will I get 2 sin (n*pi/2)" .... for any even $n$ :)

Comment: what was your original problem?

Comment: @alexjo its actually a fourier series problem. I managed to work out the problem, the only left one was the last step to get the final answer of 2 sin (n*pi/2)

Comment: If so, maybe something is wrong because $n$ must be an integer and the $LHS=0$, and the $RHS=\pm 2$